# How to provide option or arguments as suggestions to my custom command in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I have a custom command that I have created. I need it to get suggestions while using it in shell. These suggestions are basically sub-directories Ys in  a particular directory X. (X will be available in some global variable).

eg. op [tab] then i should get suggestions for all directories in the directory X.

Also, If i have to provide suggestions for commands. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features is called "autocomplete" (or similar) and there are many resources available on the [internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+autocomplete) on how to implement it in bash, for example [this](https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html) etc.

From what I get from your post, assuming your subdirectories doesn't have any spaces tabs or newlines, I think you can just:

```
complete -W "$(find "X" -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth1)" op
```

Comment: I found this very useful article which explains it all in a very nice and simple way.
https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html